# Unable to override shipping template using a custom module on Magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2.4

I'm currently having issues with overriding the default Magento Checkout `shipping.html` template using my custom module when upgrading to Magento 2.4.4. Whenever I attempt to override `shipping.html` the shipping form and shipping method on the checkout page is not being rendered. I have tested the same module with Magento 2.4.3 and confirmed that it is working as expected and the shipping form, along with the shipping method section, are being rendered properly.

[image]

The only thing I am seeing in the console browser is the following warning from `JQMigrate`

```
jquery-migrate.js:100 JQMIGRATE: HTML tags must be properly nested and closed: 
<li id="shipping" class="checkout-shipping-address" data-bind="fadeVisible: visible()">
    <div class="step-title" translate="'Shipping Address'" data-role="title" />
    <div id="checkout-step-shipping"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">

        <each if="!quoteIsVirtual" args="getRegion('customer-email')" render="" />
        <each args="getRegion('address-list')" render="" />
        <each args="getRegion('address-list-additional-addresses')" render="" />

        <!-- Address form pop up -->
        <if args="!isFormInline">
            <div class="new-address-popup">
                <button type="button"
                        class="action action-show-popup"
                        click="showFormPopUp"
                        visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
                    <span translate="'New Address'" />
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="opc-new-shipping-address"
                 visible="isFormPopUpVisible()"
                 render="shippingFormTemplate" />
        </if>

        <each args="getRegion('before-form')" render="" />

        <!-- Inline address form -->
        <render if="isFormInline" args="shippingFormTemplate" />
    </div>
</li>

<!--Shipping method template-->
<li id="opc-shipping_method"
    class="checkout-shipping-method"
    data-bind="fadeVisible: visible(), blockLoader: isLoading"
    role="presentation">
    <div class="checkout-shipping-method">
        <div class="step-title"
             translate="'Shipping Methods'"
             data-role="title" />

        <each args="getRegion('before-shipping-method-form')" render="" />

        <div id="checkout-step-shipping_method"
             class="step-content"
             data-role="content"
             role="tabpanel"
             aria-hidden="false">
            <form id="co-shipping-method-form"
                  class="form methods-shipping"
                  if="rates().length"
                  submit="setShippingInformation"
                  novalidate="novalidate">

                <render args="shippingMethodListTemplate"/>

                <div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
                    <each args="getRegion('shippingAdditional')" render="" />
                </div>
                <div role="alert"
                     if="errorValidationMessage().length"
                     class="message notice">
                    <span text="errorValidationMessage()" />
                </div>
                <div class="actions-toolbar" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
                    <div class="primary">
                        <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                            <span translate="'Next'" />
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="no-quotes-block"
                 ifnot="rates().length > 0"
                 translate="'Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time'" />
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I have the following in my `requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
           'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping': "Custom_Module/template/shipping",
        }
    }
};
```

And I have a `shipping.html` file located in the following path in my module: `app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`

I've even tried replacing my custom html with the default html found in https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html and still the same issue persists.

Comment: Are you trying to overwrite the .js file and then set a new template or just the .html file?

Comment: @MagePalExtensions the end goal was to overwrite the .js file and set a new template. But for simplicity I wanted to see if I could overwrite just the .html file and I was experiencing the same issue with both approach.

Answer (score 3):

Since Magento (Adobe Commerce) 2.4.4 you should change your HTML template and close all tags like:

```
<li id="shipping" class="checkout-shipping-address" data-bind="fadeVisible: visible()">
    <div class="step-title" translate="'Shipping Address'" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-shipping"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">

        <each if="!quoteIsVirtual" args="getRegion('customer-email')" render="" ></each>
        <each args="getRegion('address-list')" render="" ></each>
        <each args="getRegion('address-list-additional-addresses')" render="" ></each>

        <!-- Address form pop up -->
        <if args="!isFormInline">
            <div class="new-address-popup">
                <button type="button"
                        class="action action-show-popup"
                        click="showFormPopUp"
                        visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
                    <span translate="'New Address'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="opc-new-shipping-address"
                 visible="isFormPopUpVisible()"
                 render="shippingFormTemplate"></div>
        </if>

        <each args="getRegion('before-form')" render="" ></each>

        <!-- Inline address form -->
        <render if="isFormInline" args="shippingFormTemplate"></render>
    </div>
</li>

<!--Shipping method template-->
<li id="opc-shipping_method"
    class="checkout-shipping-method"
    data-bind="fadeVisible: visible(), blockLoader: isLoading"
    role="presentation">
    <div class="checkout-shipping-method">
        <div class="step-title"
             translate="'Shipping Methods'"
             data-role="title"></div>

        <each args="getRegion('before-shipping-method-form')" render="" ></each>

        <div id="checkout-step-shipping_method"
             class="step-content"
             data-role="content"
             role="tabpanel"
             aria-hidden="false">
            <form id="co-shipping-method-form"
                  class="form methods-shipping"
                  if="rates().length"
                  submit="setShippingInformation"
                  novalidate="novalidate">

                <render args="shippingMethodListTemplate"></render>

                <div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
                    <each args="getRegion('shippingAdditional')" render="" ></each>
                </div>
                <div role="alert"
                     if="errorValidationMessage().length"
                     class="message notice">
                    <span text="errorValidationMessage()"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="actions-toolbar" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
                    <div class="primary">
                        <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                            <span translate="'Next'"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="no-quotes-block"
                 ifnot="rates().length > 0"
                 translate="'Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out @Victor Tihonchuk!.

**This resolved my issue that I was seeing**. Feel kind of silly now that I didn't immediately realize this. That the console was literally telling me this the whole time .

Comment: Are these 2.4.4 template changes documented anywhere, this is an issue for custom themes with old templates?

Comment: You can see [Magento Open Source 2.4.4 Release Notes](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-4.html#infrastructure)

_HTML tags are now nested and closed properly to meet standards in JQuery 3.5.x for non-void elements including custom elements._

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var config = {
   'map': {
       '*': {
          'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html': 'Custom_ Module/template/shipping.html'
       }
    }
};
```

Then run bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately this didn't work for me